# How can I test my outgoing audio on Jitsi Meet / WebRTC?

Tags: chat, audio, bandwidth

I will be making a conference call on [Jitsi Meet](https://meet.jit.si). I want to test my audio quality (as heard by others) before I join a call.

How can I do this?

**Notes:**

- On Skype there was a contact called "Skype call testing service". You called it, it recorded a message, and then played the message back to you.
- I found https://test.webrtc.org for generic WebRTC troubleshooting, but to test connectivity and throughput you need details for a TURN or STUN server.

Are these available for Jitsi Meet?

*Needs a `[jitsi-meet]` tag.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jitsi Meet do not plan on providing an "Echo Test" service:

> ...we don't have plans to implement a pre-call device testing screen. While in a call though, you can open the device selection dialog and it will preview audio and video devices.
>
> Posted at [jitsi/jitsi-meet #1823](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/issues/1823)

However, other hosts do provide echo tests, which allows you to at least test WebRTC quality on that host. Testing with a host other than Jitsi Meet isn't ideal, but should give you mostly helpful and applicable results. One example is:

https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/echotest.html